# Interaction between Custom post type and forms

Tags: wordpress

I created a form in wordpress using a plugin and I create a custom post type named movie. I'm looking now of a way to link between my form and the custom post type.
All plugins that I found are not free (Gravity, Ninja ..) Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What plugin are you using for the form ? What have you tried so far ? Please share your code to see where your problem is. otherwise your question is too vague.

Comment: Also what do you want to do exactly with the form in conjunction with your custom post?

Comment: I want once I submit the form ( title , description , category ) , the  custom post with this attribute will be created

Comment: I think you have to write your own code to do this. Have you try anything so far?